# Angular - Template Driven form - Send array data in form of objects in an array

Tags: arrays, angular, forms, angular2-template

I'm displaying a few lists in a multiselect drop down. **The data that gets submitted is in the form**

```
[ "object1" , "object2" ]
```

**I want it to be submitted in the form:**

```
[ { object 1 } , { object 2} ]
```

My drop down list code from html:

```
<select name="service" multiple matNativeControl required ngModel>
  <option *ngFor="let service of subCategoriesList" value="{{service.id}}">{{service.service}}</option>
</select>
```

Component.ts file:

```
addPackage(form: NgForm){
    const body = {
      package_name : form.value.name,
      services: form.value.service, //the value required in objects in an array   
    }
    console.log("add package body is: ", body)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please ask a detailed question with what you want, what have you tried and what's the problem. If you want to get good response, ask a good question.  Check stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try use `Object.assign`;

in addPackage function : create an empty arry then for each selection call `Object.assign`

```
addPackage(form: NgForm){
    let selections=[];
    form.value.service.forEach(element => {
      var selection= Object.assign({}, { element });
      selections.push(selection);
    });
    const body = {
      package_name : form.value.name,
      services: selections, //put your created objects here   
    }
    console.log("add package body is: ", body)
}
```